# Oscillate counter increment?

Tags: javascript

I want to reduce the computing load in a test for primes. Currently my loop just tests odds, like so:

```
for (k=3; k<=end; k+=2) {
```

I read that every prime other than 2 and 3 is a function of k= 6 +/- 1 though. By only testing 2/3rds of the odds I can reduce computing load by 33%. The only way I can think to do this is to oscillate the counter to increment by 2, then 4, then 2, then 4 each iteration, for example testing 5, 7, 11, 13, etc.

Is there a way to tell the loop to do this? Is there another way to do this I'm not considering?

P.S. I'm aware of the sieve method of testing

Comment: Is this really a javascript question?  Sounds more like an algorithms question for SE.Math

Comment: Well I already figured out the algorithm solution (to oscillate counter), was wondering how to code it in javascript. but good point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `while` loop, instead:

```
k = 3;
odd = false;
while( k<=end ) {
    k += odd ? 2 : 4;
    odd = !odd;
}
```

Comment: :)  Exact same answer posted almost at the same time, haha.

Comment: Thanks all for the answers. MrSlayer needs the reputation more :)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
oscillate = false;
k = 3;
while(k <= end)
{
    testForPrimes(k);
    k += oscillate ? 2 : 4;
    oscillate != oscillate;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for the fun of it...

```
for (var k=3,l=0; k<=end; k+=2*(l%2+1),l++){ }
```

Comment: If you understand the `for(before; condition; end)` construct I'd argue that it's no less readable :)

Comment: No, this is definitely readable, just a bit more difficult to follow for some.  It is a very clever solution, though.  I love one liners!  Sorry if that came off negatively.

Comment: I, personally, like how the oscillating variable (`l` in this case) is limited to the scope of the loop, whereas our answers need to maintain a variable *outside* of the loop.

Comment: It's a self-contained statement but strictly speaking - unlike many compiled languages - javascript loops don't have their own scope [[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rQuEs/)].  If you want to know more have a search for *"javascript hoisting"* ;)